# Magento 2 can we have separate urls for each store

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.7

As when I need to create a separate store as each store should have separate URLs in magento2.1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. This can be done by setting the BaseURL.

Check out [this article](https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/change-baseurl-magento2/), you'll see that you can set a second BaseURL by going to **Store** > **Configuration** in the backend and finding the value under **Web**.

Now you'll have to switch the scope to your second store and change the URL

Comment: As I need url as storename.domainname.com Sander Mangel

Comment: @trilokkumar that would will work with above steps as well

Comment: I have tried it's not working for me in magento2.1.7  Sander Mangel

Comment: You're gonna need to give a bit more information :) did you clear cache, is the DNS set up properly, are the server vhosts set up properly

Comment: Yeah i have did all correctly, i have given as store url as storename.domainname.com if check in frontend by giving storename.domainname.com its redirecting to like http://localhost/magento2/default/ but i need store name in url  Sander Mangel

Comment: Sounds like you either need to clear the cache or somewhere in the code / htaccess there is a custom redirect in place

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83978/discussion-between-trilok-kumar-and-sander-mangel).